# MS Exchange -- running code against outbound email

Tags: email, database, exchange-2007, outlook-2007

I would like to know if using MS Exchange there is a way to run code against outbound emails.

The code would need to trigger on emails sent to a specific domain, connect to a database, check for an email related to the email sent, and Carbon-copy that email to the related email.

What I'm trying to do: When Jack@example.com gets an email, his auditor George@example.com gets CC'd. Jack is in a MSSQL DB table related to his auditor's email.

Are there any samples of things like this being done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are methods for this. You'll have to register as a [Transport Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579185.aspx) and there are API documents for doing this. This is in effect what Antivirus systems do. All mail will be passed through the Transport Agent. What your code does once it's passed off is up to you.

Comment: Thanks!
I'd just like to note the documentation say it is a feature of 2010.

Comment: It's also there in Server 2007, I've had to turn them off when troubleshooting AV issues, I just didn't find the MSDN link for them. This looks better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897564(EXCHG.80).aspx